# mod_rewrite with AJAX applications: possible?

Tags: proxy, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to run Shell In a Box ([link](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/)) through another server (the computer running shellinabox is not accessible from the internet) . Ideally I could use ProxyPass in the Apache config to have a reverse proxy. Problem is I can't access the conf file. So I tried using .htaccess and I discover that I cannot use ProxyPass in there. So I tried and used mod_rewrite to do the job. Currently I have the following on the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://10.1.13.236:4200/ [P]
```

However while it displays the title correctly and if I open up the source code I can see there is something in the page, nothing is diplayed on the screen (it remains blank). My suspicion is that there are problems with AJAX and this kind of proxy.

What I am trying to accomplish with the mod_rewrite as close as possible behaviour to ProxyPass (Mirorr a website in a subdirectory).

Is this possible? Is there some other solution (I tried phproxy and khproxy but neither of them is able to display anything)?

Comment: Try to determine which requests are not retrieved correctly. You could e.g. use the chrome developers tool that is build chrome itself. Then open the network tab. Try to see if you can find some 404's or something. The other way of doing this is using PHP to do the proxying (e.g. https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)